# how to restore my picker value

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Fahrenheit is `NSObject` and `WakingTemperature` is `UIViewController`. I am updating picker value from Fahrenheit to `WakingTemperature`(Basically two nsobject for Fahrenheit and Celsius to toggle, i put code for Fahrenheit).

Now I have problem restore my picker value But not happening  . here is  what i tried 
in updatelable, please help me.

```
@interface FertilityAppAppDelegate
----------------------------------
        NSInteger pickerRowCompzero;
        NSInteger pickerRowCompone;
        float valueConv;

        @property (nonatomic) NSInteger pickerRowCompzero;
        @property (nonatomic) NSInteger pickerRowCompone;
        @property (nonatomic) float valueConv;

@implementation FertilityAppAppDelegate
---------------------------------------
        @synthesize pickerRowCompzero,pickerRowCompone;
        @synthesize valueConv;

@implementation Fahrenheit
--------------------------
   - (id)init 
{        
 /* initialize data-arrays here */

 ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"36"];
 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"37"];
 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"38"];
 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"39"];
 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"40"];
 [ArrayofTempIntegerofCelsius addObject:@"41"];

 ArrayofbothTempfractional = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".0"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".1"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".2"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".3"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".4"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".5"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".6"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".7"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".8"];
 [ArrayofbothTempfractional addObject:@".9"];

 Appdelegate = (FertilityAppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


 return self;             
}



    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    { 
        [self updateLabel];
    }

    -(void) updateLabel
    {
        Appdelegate.pickerRowCompzero=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
     Appdelegate.pickerRowCompone=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];

     NSString *integer   = [ArrayofTempIntegerofFahrenheit objectAtIndex:Appdelegate.pickerRowCompzero];
     NSString *fraction  = [ArrayofbothTempfractional      objectAtIndex: Appdelegate.pickerRowCompone]; 

     NSString *fahrenheit  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",integer,fraction];
     Appdelegate.valueConv = [fahrenheit floatValue]; 

     label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",Appdelegate.valueConv];
     NSLog(@"float:%f ",Appdelegate.valueConv);

edit    // [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Now I have problem restore my picker value"? And whoch method's code were you posting (lower part of your listing)?

Comment: edit , I need to save my last selected picker value , but always coming default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed from `updateLabel`

```
Appdelegate.pickerRowCompzero=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
Appdelegate.pickerRowCompone=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
```

Changes done in `didSelectRow` method

```
Appdelegate.pickerRowCompzero=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
Appdelegate.pickerRowCompone= [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you reload your pickerview at the end of updateLabel?

to initialize your picker to a specific value xxx, you would use

```
[pickerView selectRow:xxx  inComponent:0 animated:FALSE]; // set default values
```

There is a good tutorial for an infinite picker on [link text](http://www.timespace.org/2008/07/11/the-abusive-pickerview/)

Comment: Sorry, think I still did not understand your problem. When doesn't the reload work? And when does it? - Your problem is that you have two pickers and you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa? What is the toggle option you refer to?